# Найти наибольший элемент массива и его порядковый номер

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно найти наибольший элемент массива и его порядковый номер на C#, с полноценным разбором

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста сам массив, ну или пример

Answer (score 1):

Для нахождения большего элемента в массиве(Предположим int, в вопросе не сказан тип данных) нужно сделать примерно так:

```
int maxValue = yourList.Max<int>();
```

А для определнения его индекса можно использовать [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0):

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(yourList, maxValue);
```